# Problems with deleting entities in EJB3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a question about deleting entities in EJB3.

I have two database tables: `MainCategory` and `Category`.

First, I have to find all `MainCategory` entitys' name and its `Category`, so I do this:

```
public List<MainCategory> findAllWithCategories() {
        TypedQuery<MainCategory> query = em.createNamedQuery("MainCategory.findAll", MainCategory.class);

        List<MainCategory> result = query.getResultList();

            for (MainCategory mc : result){
                try{
                    Hibernate.initialize(mc.getSubCategories());
                 }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Than I need its Categories, but I have to initialize something, so I do this (where `selectedMainCategory` is an element of  `List<MainCategory> = mainCategoryRepository.findAllWithCategories()` )

```
List<Category> mainCategories = categoryRepository.findByMainCategoryIdAndInitialze(selectedMainCategory.getId());
```

instead of this:

```
List<Category> subCategories = mainCategory.getSubCategories();
```

And after some action I need to delete a `Category`, so I do (where `selectedSubCategory` is an element of `subCategories`):

```
selectedMainCategory.getSubCategories.remove(selectedSubCategory);
mainCategoryRepository.modify(selectedMainCategory);
```

However `selectedSubCategory` hasn't been removed from `selectedMainCategory.getSubCategories()`. 
Ok, I can remove it manually if I find it by Id and manually remove from the list, but I can't find out why `getSubCategories.remove(object)` doesn't work in this case. I guess it is something about equality of two java object, but I don't know exactly. How does EJB and Java work in this case? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: How are these entities mapped? Show us their code.